# Appstore error 500 (com.apple.commerce.client)

Tags: icloud, mac-appstore

I've just formatted my SSD and reinstalled MacOS Mojave 10.14.3 (18D109). So this is a clean install. The first thing I did was try to install Keynote, Pages and Numbers.

The problem is: I cannot connect to my apple account through appstore and cannot install any app (I urgently need Keynote).

I found several people online with similar problems and followed some steps but all of them unsuccessful

I tried to sign out of icloud, restart, sign in

I tried to restart the laptop several times

I tried to clean some folder in the Library

I tried to remove the app-store configuration files

I tried to sign in on itunes and sign out

The current behavior is: I open the app store and see that I am not signed in on the lower left corner. Then I either try to sign in inputting my email and password but failing silently, or I try to install an app while signed out and it asks me to sign in. After inputting username and password the error 500 (com.apple.commerce.client) appears.

If I incorrectly insert my password, I expectedly see a message saying that the password is incorrect.

I would love to understand what the problem is and how to solve it.

Please help me!

Comment: See here also for someone else with the same problem and without any solution: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/350669/cant-install-updates-from-macos-app-store

Comment: I have an installer for iwork 2009 if it would help at all

Answer (score 13, accepted):

this worked for me (what the user 'trs96' said):
https://www.tonymacx86.com/threads/appstore-the-operation-couldnt-be-completed-com-apple-commerce-client-error-500.270957/

basicly, just fire up a terminal session and run this command:

```
defaults write com.apple.appstore.commerce Storefront -string \
    "$(defaults read com.apple.appstore.commerce Storefront | sed s/,8/,13/)"
```

Comment: YES!!!! finally a solution that worked!!

Comment: What does this do?

Comment: It's so crazy that I find a one liner solution here and the internet is awash with rubbish.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem! Before begin check the date and hour and if the timezone is correct.
First you need to clean everything from the hard drive, then install the operating system again. In the process of creating the first user account, skip the steps of the iCloud configuration, then login in the iTunes, next try login in in the App Store and see if you can access your account information and the purchases you made, if yes try to download one, and if you can't try login on your iCloud account and try download one app again, if you can't restart your Mac and try again. If anything works, call apple support and they will try to solve the problem.